# Problem in adding data through admin.firestore()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My current firestore rules in my project:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /auth_url/{auth_doc} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /nonauth_url/{nonauth_doc}{
      allow read, write: if false ;
    }
  }
}
```

---

`auth_url` collection is for authorized users and running perfectly (addition, creation, deletion etc of documents) and `nonauth_url` collection is for non authenticated users, by jquery post request through client.js I'm adding data by using `admin.firestore()` in my server (index.js) but in my cloud firestore section there is no data present there. Are my firestore rules wrong somewhere ?

---

client.js

```js
function renderList(user){

    let db = firebase.firestore() ;
    
    stopListner = db.collection('auth_url').doc(user.email).onSnapshot( (doc) => {
        var objOfObj = doc.data() ;
        let newarrOfObjects = [] ;
        
        for( key in objOfObj){
            newarrOfObjects.push(Object.assign(objOfObj[key], {name: key})) ;
        }
        $('.container.urlsList').html('') ;
        newarrOfObjects.forEach( (obj, pos) => {
            if( obj.code != ''){

                $('.container.urlsList').append(`
                <div id="accordion${pos+1}" class="myUrlSlot">
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header d-flex flex-row align-items-center p-2">
                
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-circle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#${pos+1}"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                
                <div class="w-100 code font-weight-bold">
                ${obj.code}
                </div>
                
                <button data-edit-id="${pos+1}"class="btn btn-outline-primary edit rounded-circle"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                
                
                <button data-del-id="${pos+1}" class="btn btn-outline-danger del rounded-circle"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                
                </div>
                <div id="${pos+1}" class="collapse info">
                <dl class='m-3'>
                <dt>Shortened URL</dt>
                <dd>${window.location.origin+ '/' + obj.code}</dd>
                <dt>Redirection URL</dt>
                <dd class="redirectUrl">${obj.redirectUrl}</dd>
                </dl>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                `) ;
            }
        }) ;

        if( $('div.urlsList').children().length == 0){
            $('#emptyMsg').show() ;
         }
         else{
            $('#emptyMsg').hide() ;
         }

        
        // changing plus to minus vice-versa
        
        $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.fa-plus').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus') ;
        }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.fa-minus').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus') ;
        }) ;
        
        
        // edit icon
        
        $('.edit').click(function(){
            let target_id = $(this).data('edit-id') ;
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: 'Change Redirection URL',
                centerVertical: true,
                closeButton: false,
                message: `
                <form id="changeUrlForm">
                <label for="inputUrl">Enter the New Url</label>
                <input type="url" class="form-control text-center" id="inputUrl" name="iurl" placeholder="Enter URL Here">
                </form>
                `,
                buttons: {
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'Cancel',
                        className: 'btn-danger'
                    },
                    ok: {
                        label: 'Ok',
                        className: 'btn-primary',
                        callback: function(){
                            $('#changeUrlForm').validate({
                                rules: {
                                    iurl: {
                                        required: true,
                                        url: true
                                    }
                                },
                                messages: {
                                    iurl: {
                                        url: 'Please enter a valid url with "http://" or "https://" first !!'
                                    }
                                }
                            }) ;
                            if( $('#changeUrlForm').valid()){
                                let newurl = $('#inputUrl').val() ;

                                var objToBeUpdated = `url${target_id}` ;

                                var updateObj = {} ;

                                updateObj[`${objToBeUpdated}.redirectUrl`] = newurl ;

                                db.collection('auth_url').doc(user.email).update(updateObj).then( () => {
                                    successAlert(`URL${target_id}'s redirection url updated successfully !!`) ;
                                }).catch( err => {
                                    errorAlert(err.code, err.message) ;
                                }) ;

                            }
                            else{
                                $('label.error').addClass('text-danger');
                                return false ;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) ;
        }) ;
        
        // del icon
        
        $('.del').click(function(){
            let target_id = $(this).data('del-id') ;
            bootbox.confirm({
                message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this saved URL ?',
                centerVertical: true,
                closeButton: false,
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label: 'Yes',
                        className: 'btn-success'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'No',
                        className: 'btn-danger'
                    }
                },
                callback: function(result){
                    if(result){
                        var updateObj = {
                            [`url${target_id}`]: {
                                code: '',
                                redirectUrl: ''
                            }
                        } ;

                        db.collection('auth_url').doc(user.email).update(updateObj).then(() => {
                            successAlert(`URL${target_id} deleted successfully !!`) ;
                        }).catch( err => {
                            errorAlert(err.code, err.message) ;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }) ;
        }) ;
    }, (err) => {
        errorAlert(err.code, err.message) ;
    }) ;
}





$(function(){
    // on authorization endering is working perfectly fine
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      if( user ){
         if( firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified == false ){
            bootbox.dialog(verifyDialogSettings);
         }
         
         if( firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].providerId === 'google.com'){
            $('.changePass, .beforechangePass').hide() ;
         }
         refreshMainPage( user ) ;
         // refreshUrls(user.email) ;
         console.log('signed in state') ;
         $('.login, #newurl, .mainTopic, .middle').hide() ;
         $('.signOutButton, .settings, .welcomemsg, .image, .description, .urlsList').show() ;
         
         // refresh the list
         
         renderList(user) ;
      }
      else{
         console.log('signed out state') ;
         $('.signOutButton, .settings, .welcomemsg, .image, .description, .urlsList, #emptyMsg').hide() ;
         $('.login, #newurl, .mainTopic, .middle').show() ;
      }
   });
   
   
   
$('.sendUrl').on('click', function(e){
      
      e.preventDefault() ;
      $('#nonauthForm').validate({
         rules: {
            url_nauth: {
               required: true,
               url: true
            }
         }
      }) ;

      if( $('#nonauthForm').valid()){
         $.post('/nonauth_url',{
               URL: $('#url').val()
            },function(code, status){
               if(status === 'success'){
                  $('#newurl').html(`
                  ${window.location.origin+ '/'+ code}
                  `)
               }
         }) ;
      }
      else{
         $('label.error').addClass('text-danger d-block mt-2');
      }  
}) ;




}) ;
```

---

index.js (server)

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin') ;
const express = require('express') ;
const urlId = require('shortid') ;

const sp = require('synchronized-promise') ;

const string = require('randomstring') ;

const serviceAccount = require('./url-shortner-xxxx.json') ;

const app = express() ;

admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let db = admin.firestore() ;
let Data = db.collection('nonauth_url') ;

app.post('/nonauth_url', (req, res) => {
   
   let codeGenerated = 'n' + urlId.generate() ; // n for non-authenticated users
   
   let docname = 'doc-' + string.generate(4) ;
   
   let schema = {
      code: codeGenerated,
      url: req.body.URL,
      expiredAt: Date.now()+600000  // in milisceonds for 10min
   }
   
   let docRef = Data.doc(docname).set(schema) ;
   res.send(schema.code) ;
}) ;

exports.routeFunc = functions.https.onRequest(app) ;
```

`res.send(schema.code)` is sending back the code but not creating any docs under `nonauth_url` collection

Comment: Please also show the code that is not working as you expect it to against these rules.

Comment: When using the Firebase Admin SDK, requests are not affected by security rules.  Rules only apply to code running on mobile and web clients.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry, I have added the code for client.js and index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending an HTTP response indicates the end of execution for a running function. You need to wait for the `set()` to complete before responding:

```
let docRef = Data.doc(docname).set(schema).then(() => {
  res.send(schema.code);
});
```